# Compress files on S3 and download with PHP

Tags: php, amazon-s3, laravel-5, compression

I have an app where I need to allow users to download many media items at once, possibly over 500. We do all our storage on S3 and I am finding it difficult to handle a large request of media, potentially over 400 items.

I was wondering, does anybody know of a way to compress the media on S3 and then download a single archive? Is that supported? If not, can anyone recommend a service that would accomplish this?

Our current setup is set to download all the media from S3 and then compress it locally but we are running into server timeouts when we try to accomplish this on a large scale.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The bad news is that the [AWS PHP SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/) doesn't support zipping out of the box.

The good news is that there are several 3rd-party libraries that do this for you, e.g.:

- PHP: https://github.com/jmathai/s3-bucket-stream-zip-php
- Javascript: https://github.com/orangewise/s3-zip
- Go: https://github.com/Teamwork/s3zipper

Comment: Seems that just allows for bucket zipping...do you know any tools that would allow me to cherry pick files?